# E_ERROR: Call to a member function getPath() on null in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting a frequent error which is not yet digested and reason behind it. This is the error message:

```
E_ERROR: Call to a member function getPath() on null: Call to a member function getPath() on null
```

The language is PHP 5.6.30

Raw JSON

```
{
    "body": {
        "trace": {
            "frames": [], 
                "exception": {
                    "message": "Call to a member function getPath() on null", 
        "class": "E_ERROR: Call to a member function getPath() on null"
      }
    }
  }, 
  "uuid": "6c05deb9-3012-42a8-9d90-aa8b1a9db170", 
  "language": "PHP 5.6.30", 
  "level": "critical", 
  "timestamp": 1496644452, 
  "request": {
    "body": "", 
    "GET": [], 
    "url": "http://vikaserp.in/phpinfo.php", 
    "user_ip": "106.193.164.49", 
    "headers": {
      "Accept-Language": "en-US%2Cen%3Bq=0.5", 
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
      "Connection": "keep-alive", 
      "Accept": "text%2Fhtml%2Capplication%2Fxhtml_xml%2Capplication%2Fxml%3Bq=0_9%252C%252A%252F%252A%253Bq%3D0.8", 
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0", 
      "Host": "vikaserp.in", 
      "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1"
    }, 
    "query_string": "", 
    "POST": [], 
    "method": "GET"
  }, 
  "server": {
    "host": "host.vikaserp.in", 
    "argv": []
  }, 
  "environment": "production", 
  "platform": "Linux host.vikaserp.in 2.6.32-042stab120.11 #1 SMP Wed Nov 16 12:05:45 MSK 2016 x86_64", 
  "framework": "unknown", 
  "notifier": {
    "version": "1.0.1", 
    "name": "rollbar-php"
  }, 
  "metadata": {
    "customer_timestamp": 1496644451
  }
}
```

This is the information I have right now but I can get more if needed. Could you please share what went wrong here? I am not technical so please go easy on me. Thanks!

Comment: Will be better if you share the source code which caused this error. This JSON is just the body of the error..

Comment: this will produce same error: `$test = null; $test->getPath();`

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: Hi Team, thank you for reaching here and sharing the points. We were able to find the issue internally from what @Kazz mentioned. So it is fixed. Thank you very much.